# How to query the mysql database by changing the date formats

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `stock_historic` (
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

Parsing from  an csv file , i have inserted data into the table this way

```
Insert Into stock_historic values('SRF', '20150930' , '11190.00');
Insert Into stock_historic values('SRF', '20151001' , '11456.00');
```

But from the front end the (Jquery date picker) date comes in this format

```
select * from  stock_historic where symbol = "SRF.NS" and startDate = "2015-09-30" and endDate = "2015-10-01"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91ac8d/1

Please let me know how can i query the database in this case

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `-` from the dates that come from the datepicker before you put them into the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alter your table structure and give the date column another name (`date` is a reserved word) and an appropriate column type like timestamp or date

```
CREATE TABLE `stock_historic` (
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opendte` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

now you don't have to bother about formats as long as its not ambigous. All of your examples should work.

Answer (score 2):

Format the date of jQuery date picker, remove the dashes. For example:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    "dateFormat": "yymmdd"
});
```

I think it will be better formatting in javascript than in query, you can put it directly in your queries.

Comment: Thanks , in that case how the mysql date between utility works .

Comment: if you want to use mysql between function, change the type of column to `DATE` type or `DATETIME` type